# Significance of k-forms

Tags: vector-analysis

What is the necessity of introducing k-forms in vector calculus?

One argument I came across for these forms was that they allow integration over their basis. Sure the wedge product introduces nice properties like antisymmetry, however, is there a need except that to introduce these k-forms?

Comment: It allows to integrate, but most importantly it does it in a coordinate-free way.